# Import XML To SQL Multiple Node With The Same Name

Tags: xml

I've been asked to import data that we're receiving from a 3rd party and it isn't formatted in the way I would like. Below is a very simplified version of what I'm receiving...

```
<data>
    <stage>
        <deldate>17-OCT-2023</deldate>
        <deltime>12:00</deltime>
        <status>Failed</status>
        <code>1</code>
    </stage>
    <stage>
        <deldate>24-OCT-2023</deldate>
        <deltime>13:00</deltime>
        <status>Success</status>
        <code>2</code>
    </stage>
</data>
```

The two "stage" nodes each relate to a collection and delivery portion of a transport job, with code 1 being collection  and code 2 being delivery. With the way the XML is formatted, importing this will give me 2 rows of 4 columns but I need it 1 row of 8 columns. The code I'm using to extract the data is below...

```
SELECT
   MY_XML.data.query('deldate').value('.', 'date')AS Date,
   MY_XML.data.query('deltime').value('.', 'time')AS Time,
   MY_XML.data.query('status').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')AS Status,
   MY_XML.data.query('code').value('.', 'int')AS Code
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\SFLYNN01\Desktop\TestXML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('data/stage') AS MY_XML (data);
```

Result is as follows...

[image]

How can I retrieve the results as follows...

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat simpler and more performant way.

**SQL**

```
WITH rs (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\SFLYNN01\Desktop\TestXML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
SELECT c.value('(stage[code/text()="1"]/deldate/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS Date1
    , c.value('(stage[code/text()="1"]/deltime/text())[1]', 'TIME(0)') AS Time1
    , c.value('(stage[code/text()="1"]/status/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Status1
    , c.value('(stage[code/text()="1"]/code/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Code1
    , c.value('(stage[code/text()="2"]/deldate/text())[1]', 'DATE') AS Date2
    , c.value('(stage[code/text()="2"]/deltime/text())[1]', 'TIME(0)') AS Time2
    , c.value('(stage[code/text()="2"]/status/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Status2
    , c.value('(stage[code/text()="2"]/code/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Code2
FROM rs
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/data') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| Date1 | Time1 | Status1 | Code1 | Date2 | Time2 | Status2 | Code2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-17 | 12:00:00 | Failed | 1 | 2023-10-24 | 13:00:00 | Success | 2 |

Comment: True, this is simpler, but more performant? How do you measure that because all of this stuff is done in memory, and with only 4 (or 8?) fields I would not know how to measure the difference in performance... 

Comment: Actually your solution is, a bit, faster.  But a lot of time is spent in the evaluation of the [XPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfaNH.png)    (see the pasted plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJyI9YpWa )

Comment: This works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
   MY_XML.data.query('deldate').value('.', 'date')AS Date,
   MY_XML.data.query('deltime').value('.', 'time')AS Time,
   MY_XML.data.query('status').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')AS Status,
   MY_XML.data.query('code').value('.', 'int')AS Code
FROM (SELECT CAST(XML AS xml)
      FROM xml) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('data/stage') AS MY_XML (data)
)
SELECT 
    t1.Date as Date1, t1.Time as Time1, t1.Status as Status1, t1.Code as Code1,
    t2.Date as Date2, t2.Time as Time2, t2.Status as Status2, t2.Code as Code2
FROM cte as t1
INNER JOIN cte as t2 on t2.Code=2
WHERE t1.Code=1
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/1dS2kOb2)